# Process much data multithreaded with fix number of threads and allowing exceptions

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm going through large text files (5GB) line-by-line with the main thread. A few other threads are created to format these lines simultaneously.

I've written a solution using the `Runnable` class with `Semaphore`, which controls the amount of threads running. Unfortunately `Runnable` doesn't offer a return value or throwing exceptions. And I want my whole application to stop if a exception in any thread is thrown.

I'm trying to use `Callable` and `Future` now, but I get out of memory errors.

```
public class ProcessLine implements Callable<Boolean> {
  private final String inputLine;

  public ProcessLine(String inputLine) {
    this.inputLine = inputLine;
  }

  @Override
  public Boolean call() throws Exception {
    formatLine(inputLine); // huge method which can throw exceptions

    return true;
  }
}
```

And before opening the text file:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads, new DaemonThreadFactory());
List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<Future>();
```

Then within the loop which iterates through all lines:

```
ProcessLine processLine = new ProcessLine(inputLine);

Future f = executor.submit(processLine);
futures.add(f);
```

First problem here is that all `Future` objects are collected in the `futures` List. It's no surprise I'm running out of memory when I have one item per line.

Second problem is: I'd check all `Future` items with the `get()` method at the very end of processing the text file. I'd not even notice if the first line had thrown an exception.

Please help me finding out how to solve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a few other solutions, but I think I've found the best for me by myself.

```
public static final ThreadStatus threadStatus = new ThreadStatus();

public static class ThreadStatus {
 private Exception exception = null;

 public void setException(Exception exception) {
   if(exception == null) {
     return;
   }

   this.exception = exception;
 }

 public Exception getException() {
   return exception;
 }

 public boolean exceptionThrown() {
   return exception != null;
 }
```

}

Then in the thread's `run()` method:

```
catch(Exception e) {
  Main.threadStatus.setException(e);
}
```

And within the loop which iterates through all lines:

```
if(Main.threadStatus.exceptionThrown()) {
  throw Main.threadStatus.getException();
}
```

Thanks to all who helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the number of pending tasks, by creating a custom `ThreadPoolExecutor` using [this constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#ThreadPoolExecutor%28int,%20int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue%29) as follows:

```
ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
        threads,
        threads,
        0L,
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(WORK_QUEUE_SIZE));
```

where `WORK_QUEUE_SIZE` determines the maximum number of pending lines.

---

Here's another approach that I came up with. I'm not sure how to incorporate `ExecutorService` in an elegant way.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;

public class Scratch {

    static Object lock = new Object();
    static AtomicBoolean keepRunning = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    static BlockingQueue<String> buf = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>(100);
    static List<Consumer> consumers  = Arrays.asList(new Consumer(),
                                                     new Consumer(),
                                                     new Consumer(),
                                                     new Consumer());

    public static void main(String [] args) {    

        // Start a producer
        new Producer().start();

        // Start consumers
        for (Consumer c : consumers)
            c.start();
    }

    static void stopConsumers() {
        System.out.println("Stopping consumers");
        keepRunning.set(false);
        for (Consumer c : consumers)
            c.interrupt();
    }

    static class Producer extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try (BufferedReader br =
                    new BufferedReader(new FileReader("lines.txt"))) {
                String line;
                while (null != (line = br.readLine())) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    buf.put(line);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // Producer exception
            }

            // Wait for the consumers to finish off the last lines in the queue
            synchronized (lock) {
                while (!buf.isEmpty()) {
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO: Deal with interruption
                    }
                }
            }

            // The consumers are now hanging on buf.take. Interrupt them!
            stopConsumers();
        }
    }


    static class Consumer extends Thread {

        // Dummy process
        private boolean process(String str) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            return true;
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Starting");

            while (keepRunning.get()) {
                try {
                    process(buf.take());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO: Handle interrupt
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    stopConsumers();  // Processing exception: Graceful shutdown
                }

                // Notify the producer that the queue might be empty.
                synchronized (lock) {
                    lock.notify();
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Stopping");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens if my text file has more than the allowed `Integer.MAX_VALUE` in `WORK_QUEUE_SIZE`? And what about the `Future` problems?

Comment: No no, the WORK_QUEUE_SIZE determines how many pending Futures you can have at any point in time. You can put 1 there if you like.

Comment: Updated with regard to your second problem.

Comment: If I call `.get()` right after `executor.submit()`, I know instantly if the format thread threw an exception. But my main thread must wait for the computation in the format thread to complete. That prevents my threads to run simultaneously and makes the multithreading nonsensical. Right? I'm always using 4 format threads and now my application takes 4 times longer.

Comment: Well can't you let the ProcessLine take care of the termination logic then? Or put the results in another queue which is processed by a result processor.

Comment: Let me know if you're still struggling. I may find time to give you a code example.

Comment: I'm currently working on it, thanks. I'm editing my old solution. I created a method `exit()` which the main application and the threads call, if they fail. Not sure whether that's dirty, because I'd like to have a single exit point in my app.

Comment: Added another approach. See if you can grasp the code.

Comment: I tried your solution. It has a small bug because `c.interrupt();` kills all threads too early. I've found a solution and posted my answer here, too. Many thanks for your effort.

Comment: Sounds strange. Perhaps you called `stopConsumers()` prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

So, storing all the results of the processing by the tasks (using a `Future` for each) takes too much memory, but you could do further processing on those results individually,  without having a complete set (right?).

You could consider having each task pass its result onto *another* work queue for processing by another thread pool. If the second work queue has fixed size, memory use is guaranteed to be finite. This is a variant of the *pipes and filters* design pattern. It has the nice characteristic that if the processing of the second stage is too slow,  eventually the second work queue will fill up, causing the threads of the first thread pool to block. More CPU time then becomes available to the threads of the second thread pool. That is, it automatically shares CPU time between the thread pools in  a manner that maximises throughput.

The result of processing the first line of the file is guaranteed to be examined within a finite time if the start of processing (when the number of lines processed is equal to the size of the second queue), which can be used to satisfy your requirement for prompt processing of problems.

I've used this design for a program that down loaded data and wrote it to files, to prevent the program holding on to too much data that was awaiting processing.